# Can't get Wi-Fi dongle to work

Tags: usb, wifi, wireless, realtek

I bought a generic Wi-Fi dongle that, according to the comments of the people who bought it, worked out of the box on Raspbian. Well, turns out it didn't. I'm struggling to make it work. I'm using Raspbian 3.10.25 on a Model B via ssh.

`iwconfig`

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

I first suspected there was a missing firmware. `lsusb` identifies the device as `148f:7601 Ralink Technology, Corp`. `firmware-ralink` was indeed installed out of the box, and according to some forum posts that indeed is the firmware for devices with `148f:7601 Ralink` id. So I guess the modules should be loaded... `lsmod | grep -v snd`:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
leds_gpio               2059  0 
led_class               3688  1 leds_gpio
```

Apart from the sound modules only the LED modules are loaded. I guess there's something wrong with that... I tried loading some available modules... `ls /lib/modules/3.10.25+/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/`:

```
at76c50x-usb.ko  b43        hostap    libertas_tf        mwifiex  rndis_wlan.ko  rtl818x    zd1201.ko
ath              b43legacy  libertas  mac80211_hwsim.ko  p54      rt2x00         rtl8192cu  zd1211rw
```

I tried modprobing everything in there with a "rt" prefix, `wlan0` still didn't show on `iwconfig`.

I'm at loss. Any ideas? The dongle came with a "driver" DVD. It consists of multiple folders of what seem to be multiple drivers for several different hardware. The documentation is missing for most of them and incorrect for the ones it's present. I tried to unzip and then `make && make install` everything under the "Linux" directory that didn't have "Android" in the filename, but `make` gives several errors and editing the makefiles without a manual would be challenging.

Comment: You may check the output `lsusb -vvv` for the device model and if it is compatible with RPi on http://elinux.org/RPi_USB_Wi-Fi_Adapters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not worth spending time trying to get this WiFi dongle working. It takes [too many steps](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=49864&start=175) and all that effort goes down the drain everytime the kernel or anything else gets updated.

Your best option is to return/sell/throw the Ralink 7601 and get an RTL8188CUS-based dongle.